# como adicionar espaço em branco entre as Strings

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Boas,

Tenho 2 campos: Nome e Sobrenome.
na saída os 2 nomes saem colados sem espaço entre eles.

deste ja agradeço a ajuda.

[image: print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar o espaço na concatenação de strings:

```
var texto1 = "" + Enter.text!
var texto2 = "" + Enter1.text!
myLabel.text = texto1 =  + " " + texto2
```

Comment: OPS! não funcionou, na pratica apenas funciona se ao escrever o primeiro nome der um espaço. A saída dos dois nomes sai correctamente

Comment: Alterei a resposta, testa como fiz lá agora.

Comment: Não funcionou, O Xcode diz: Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand.

Comment: `myLabel.text = Enter.text!  + " " + Enter1.text!`

Comment: Por convenção voce deveria nomear as suas variáveis começando com letra minúscula. `myLabel.text = enter.text! + " " + enter1.text!`

Comment: Funcionou, a princípio deu um erro por não ter a variáveis texto e texto1 em nenhuma outra parte do código substitui por underscore e deu

_ = " " + Enter.text!
_ = " " + Enter1.text!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma:

```
myLabel.text = "\(Enter.text!) \(Enter1.text!)"
```

Comment: myLabel.text = text1.text! +  " "  + text2.text!